# jQuery 1 form to lookup, Ajax post to lookup, second form to add if not found

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I'm in Classic ASP using jQuery in the following scenario:

1) User types a client id (banner id) formatted [R]\d{8} and presses Search button in #searchForm:

```
<form id="searchForm" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="bannerID" class="required" id="bannerID" value=""/>
    <input type="submit"  class="button" id="searchClients" value="Continue">
</form>
```

2) Search form invokes a search function (AJAX POST to another ASP Classic page that returns results or a NOTFOUND):

```
 $('#searchForm').submit(function() {
  /*   ASSUMING THE BANNERID (STUDENT ID) MATCHES THE RIGHT FORMAT, SEARCH FOR IT  */
    sendSearchRequest(text)
    return false;
});
```

3) If a matching record is found, present the user with the option to leave the page and edit the client record or add information about that client (a tutorial). Otherwise, show a hidden Add User Form:

```
function sendSearchRequest(text) {
/*   POST THE BANNERID (USER ID) TO A PAGE TO CHECK IF IT EXISTS  */
        var jsonToSend={ bannerid: text} ;

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: 'staff_client_search_single_ajax.asp',
               data: jsonToSend,
               success: function(response) {
               if (response=="NOTFOUND") {
            /*   COULD BE A NEW CLIENT OR A MISKEYED CLIENT ID; */
                 $('#newClientForm').fadeIn('slow');
                 $('#spnBannerID').text(text);
                 $('#divSearch').fadeOut('slow');
                 }
               else
               {
                    $("#user-info").html(response);
                    var user_id=$('#existing-user-id').text();
                    $('#existing-user-id').css('display','none');
                    dialog_ShowUserFound(user_id);
                }
               },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
           }); // end ajax
        }
}) // document ready
```

4) Post comes back "NOT FOUND," I hide the first form and show a second to add the client:

```
<div id="newClientForm" style="display:none;">
<form id="addClientForm">
    <label for="spnBannerID">Banner ID</label>:&nbsp;<span name="spnBannerID" id="spnBannerID" style='font-weight:bold'></span>
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value=""/>
</form>
```

5) Neither the first nor the second form are posted back; their submit handlers are blocked and I do AJAX calls instead:

```
$('#searchForm').submit(function() {
 /*   ASSUMING THE BANNERID (STUDENT ID) MATCHES THE RIGHT FORMAT, SEARCH FOR IT  */
sendSearchRequest(text)
return false;
});

$('#addClientForm').submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

6) The problem comes when the user is in the ADD CLIENT form and realizes that even though he provided a valid client ID (R\d{8)), he didn't put in the right one, so he wants to go back to the start and enter the correct one.

He presses back, and the page is returned to a state after the AJAX search POST, not to the initial search form. The URL shows page.asp?bannerid=R11234123 , which reflects the posted search form.

How do I set it up so if the user presses "back" from the Add form, he goes to the start and not back to the just-posted search?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into using a history plugin and trigger changes in state when forms get changed. As you listen for these changes, if your code didn't trigger them, then it was a back button that did and you can then get the state and show appropriate content/form. Consider a standard page, no script with internal page links to sections of content, or "back to top". Clicking a back button in browser after clicking one of these links returns you to prior position in page. This is due to hashchange events and state change. History plugins make it easier to manage these events/states cross browser.

A couple to look at:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js